# How to copy values of one column to another based on condition in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My code, which is as below, sends the tickets to the emails present in the 1st column. So if there are 7 tickets and 2 emails, the program iterates through emails and sends all the tickets. My question is when all of the emails are sent, how do I assign the email ID to the owner column.

Example: I know for sure that all tickets will be sent to the email IDs in column "1", how do I assign the email IDs from "1" to all 7 rows in the column "owner".

I have the following input which is in the file "combo.csv"

```
0            1                 2                 3     owner
0   0   sunith@email.com    116675  Random Message 1    NaN
1   1   sunith@email.com    116674  Random Message 2    NaN
2   2   NaN                 116675  Random Message 3    NaN
3   3   NaN                 116676  Random Message 4    NaN
4   4   NaN                 116677  Random Message 5    NaN
5   5   NaN                 116678  Random Message 6    NaN
6   6   NaN                 116679  Random Message 7    NaN
```

Please help

```
e = pd.read_csv('combo.csv')
f = e.fillna("")
print(f)
emails = f['1'].values
email_index = 0
count_of_emails = len(emails)
print("count of emails" + str(count_of_emails))
ticket_number = list(f['2'].values)
desc_value = f['3'].values
for ticket_index in range(len(ticket_number)):
    if not emails[email_index]:
        continue
    if email_index != count_of_emails:
        print("resetting email Index")
        email_index = 0
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    if not ticket_number[ticket_index]:
        message = f'Random Message'
    else:
        message = f'Hello the ticket number {int(ticket_number[ticket_index])} with the Description {desc_value[ticket_index]} has been assigned to ' \
                  f'you. '
        adding_owner = pd.read_csv('combo.csv')
        adding_owner['owner'] = emails
        owner_added = adding_owner.copy()
        # del owner_added['4']
        owner_added = owner_added.loc[:, ~owner_added.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
        owner_added.to_csv('combo.csv')

    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = emails[email_index]
    mail.Subject = 'This is a test'
    mail.HTMLBody = message
    mail.Send()
    print("Sent email to" + emails[email_index])
    email_index = email_index + 1
```

If all the emails are sent then the output should look like

```
Output:

   0            1                  2                 3     owner
    0   0   sunith@email.com    116675  Random Message 1    sunith@email.com
    1   1   sunith@email.com    116674  Random Message 2    sunith@email.com
    2   2   NaN                 116675  Random Message 3    sunith@email.com
    3   3   NaN                 116676  Random Message 4    sunith@email.com
    4   4   NaN                 116677  Random Message 5    sunith@email.com
    5   5   NaN                 116678  Random Message 6    sunith@email.com
    6   6   NaN                 116679  Random Message 7    sunith@email.com
```

Comment: Please simplify by showing a sample of what you want your table to look like in an  output example

Comment: Hi. I edited the post and gave a sample output. I hope that helps.

Comment: So for different emails in column 1, different tickets may go to different emails? A particular ticket goes only to one email?

Comment: If there are 7 different emails, the tickets will be assigned to all 7. However, if there are only let's say 2 emails then all the tickets get assigned to only those two.

Comment: But the tickets are unique to each email? Example: Ticket 1 will go to only one of the emails in column 1 and not more?

Comment: No. They are not unique to each email, I set a counter for the email index, when the number of emails is less than the number of tickets, then the program loops over the emails and assigns all the tickets.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables are broken down into .csv per unique email, the simplest solution would be:

```
In [57]: test.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 3].ffill()

In [58]: df
Out[58]:
                  0       1               2                 3
0  sunith@email.com  116675               1  sunith@email.com
1  sunith@email.com  116674               2  sunith@email.com
2               NaN  116675               3  sunith@email.com
3               NaN  116676               4  sunith@email.com
4               NaN  116677               5  sunith@email.com
5               NaN  116678               6  sunith@email.com
6               NaN  116679               7  sunith@email.com
```

Comment: Hi. It doesn't work if the column headings are "1", "2", "3" etc. Is there any other solution if the headers are numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure if your column names are numbers or strings.   
Whatever they are, I updated my answer to the "canonical and proper" format of column selection using brackets.

Comment: They are numbers as the concat method replaces the headings with numbers. I'll try this solution and let you know.

Comment: The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) on indexing(selection) of columns and rows. Use whatever method works. I edited my answer using numerical indexing.